# Unity webgl: Unable to parse Build/vectorunknown builds.framework.js.gz! enable "Content-Encoding: gzip" in response headers in github pages

Tags: unity-game-engine, github-pages

I have a unity webgl project and I pushed the webgl build to my git branch as shown below.

[image]

I deployed this branch to my github page as shown below.

[image]

The build is working on my local with the help of [servez](https://greggman.github.io/servez/). However, on github pages (and my local without servez) it gives the following error:

> Unable to parse Build/vectorunknown builds.framework.js.gz! This can
> happen if build compression was enabled but web server hosting the
> content was misconfigured to not serve the file with HTTP Response
> Header "Content-Encoding: gzip" present. Check browser Console and
> Devtools Network tab to debug.

How do I deploy to github page with "Content-Encoding: gzip" response header included? How do I make it work? Do I need to make webgl with different options in Unity instead? Kindly help!

Comment: Unity requires very specific encoding on the web server.   Or you build without compression

Comment: yeah. i changed player settings to disable compression and I am trying that out now.

Comment: Probably it means that Github is not configured to correctly serve those file types ... I know that at last e.g. fr testing your WebgL things on IIS you need to explicitly overwrite the mime type mapping

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I went to `Edit > Project Settings > Player > Publishing settings` and disabled the compression. it worked after that. However, the colors look weird after that. i wish there was another better way.
[image]

Comment: There is. Use a web server configured to work with unity's requirements.

Comment: Follow unitys setup instructions i cant add any more because when you do its always worked

Comment: @BugFinder Can you provide a link to Unity's setup instructions for configuring a web server? Do you mean https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.1/Documentation/Manual/webgl-deploying.html ?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error message. When I inspected network traffic using browser developer tools, I could see no "Content-Encoding: gzip" response header. I added the mime types required by Unity to the server configuration, but still couldn't get the needed Content-Encoding response header to appear.

However, I found that enabling Player Settings > Publishing Settings > **Decompression fallback** solved the problem for me. According to [these docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.1/Documentation/Manual/webgl-deploying.html), "The decompression fallback option enables Unity to automatically embed a JavaScript decompressor into your build. This decompressor corresponds to your selected compression method, and decompresses your content if the browser fails to do so."

Presumably there's a somewhat slower startup because of having to download the JavaScript decompressor.

Comment: wow how did you figure this - of all possible things - out!

Comment: @ina I don't remember exactly, but since it was having trouble handling the decompression (parsing gzip), I probably thought a fallback method for decompression might work.